# Informatica PowerCenter pipelines to Azure Data Factory

Tags: ssis, etl, azure-data-factory, informatica-powercenter, azure-synapse

I am trying to move my informatica pipelines in PC 10.1 to Azure Data Factory/ Synapse pipelines. Other than rewriting them from scratch, is there a way to migrate them somehow.. I am not finding any tools to achieve this as well. Has anyone faced this problem. Any leads on how to proceed ahead.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are no out of box solutions available to complete this migration. Unfortunately, you will have to author them again.

Answer (score 1):

Informatica PowerCenter pipelines are a **physical** implementation of an Extract Transform Load (ETL) process.  Each provider has different approaches to the implementations and they do not necessarily map well from one to another.  Core Azure Data Factory (ADF) is actually more suited to Extract, Load and Transform (ELT), unless of course you use Data Flows.

So what you have to do is:

- map out **physically** what your current pipeline is doing, if you don't have that documentation already.  A simple spreadsheet template mapping out the components of the existing pipeline, tracking source, target plus any transformations will suffice
- **logically** map out what the pipeline is doing; ie without using PowerCenter- specific terminology lay out what the "as is" pipeline is doing.  A [data flow diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-flow_diagram) is a great way to do this
- **logically** map out what the "to be" pipeline should do; ie without using any ADF-specific terminology, attempt to refine the "as is" pipeline to its simplest form
- using expert knowledge of the ADF components (eg Copy, Lookup, Notebook, Stored Proc to name but a few) map from the logical "to be" to the physical (in the loosest sense of the word, it's all cloud now right : ), eg move data from place to place with the [Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview) activity, transform data in a SQL database using the Stored Proc activity, a repeated activity might use a For Each loop (bear in mind these execute in parallel), do sophisticated transformations or processing using Databricks notebooks if required and so on.  If you require a low-code approach, consider Data Flows.

So you can see it's just a few simple steps.  Good luck!

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.. Since there is no tool, I was just wondering if there is some way we can query the metadata in the informatica pipelines and reduce the manual effort in going to the 500 odd pipelines individually to gather the existing ETL logic.. that will ease some of the pain

Comment: Well that would help with step 1 above.  There is an API for creating ADF pipelines programmatically which you can see here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-rest-api